# Using explode in another foreach

Tags: php, foreach, limit, explode

I've been using explode in a separate foreach, but now I want to use it in existing foreach, which I find hard. Instead of the name of the screenshot it echos "Array". What am I doing wrong and how can I limit it to just one of the screenshots, not up to four?

```
<?php $game = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$game->select = 'idProgramGame, dk_name, dk_text, picture, recordType, screenshot';
$game->from = 'programsgames';
$game->where = 'dk_name IS NOT NULL';
$game->where = 'featured = 2';
$game->where = 'points = 100';
$game->where = 'recordType = "g"';
$game->order = 'date DESC';
$game->limit = '1'; 

$gameresult = $game->query();

foreach($gameresult as $gamerow) {
            echo '<a href="http://www.domain.com/Yii/index.php/programsgames/';
            echo $gamerow['idProgramGame'];
            echo '">';
            echo '<br><div class="image"><h2><span><b>';
            echo $gamerow['dk_name'];
            echo '</b></span></h2>';
            echo '<center><img src="http://www.domain.com/upload/';
            echo explode(';',$gamerow['screenshot']); 
            echo '" height="250" align="center" alt="';
            echo $gamerow['dk_name'];
            echo '"></center>';
            echo '</a></div><br><br><br>';


            }

?>
```

Comment: `echo explode(';',$gamerow['screenshot']); ` - you are trying to echo out an array which results in this string ('Array').

Comment: Sorry I'm new in coding. So I've to make some kind of function before or in the query and call that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to debug, you should always simplify your code as much as possible, while still getting the error.

In this case, you've already established that your `echo explode(";",$gamerow['screenshot']);` line is at fault here, so you should investigate [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) and how it works.

In particular, you'll notice that it returns an array. Reading up on arrays will tell you that if you try to just echo it, it outputs `Array`, literally.

Now, I don't know what's in `$gamerow['screenshot']`, but I'm going to guess that it's something like this:

```
something.png;otherstuffhere
```

If that's the case, then your solution depends on if your PHP is up-to-date.

If it is, just do this:

```
echo explode(";",$gamerow['screenshot'])[0];
```

If not, you have to use a temporary variable:

```
$parts = explode(";",$gamerow['screenshot']);
echo $parts[0];
```

For future reference, to output the contents of an array for debugging purposes, use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) or a related function.

Comment: Amazing! A great, functional and educational answer that was very helpful. The second solution worked for me, so I have something to check up on. If you offer paid help please mail me at martin@dlc.dk as I have one more complex problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo explode(';',$gamerow['screenshot']);
```

explode() will return an array of all values seperated by ';', but echo() can't display arrays. You could just loop through that array from explode() using foreach:

```
foreach(explode(';',$gamerow['screenshot']) as $screenshot){
    echo($screenshot);
}
```

Comment: Considering the context of the erroneous `echo`, I don't think this is the desired output.

Comment: Niet is quite right here as I already knew that I just had a hard time implementing that in the existing foreach with my limited coding skills.